# Why my LSTM model stays between loss: 0.3 to 0.5 and accuracy: 0.3 to 0.5? Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

I have this Sequential model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM( 264 , input_shape = _in, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM( 132, return_sequences = True ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM( 64 ,return_sequences = True ) )
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add( Dense( 32 ,activation = 'relu') )
model.add( Dropout(0.2))

model.add( Dense( 2, activation='softmax') )
model.summary()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD( lr = 0.01 )

model.compile(
     loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
     optimizer = optimizer,
     metrics   = [   'accuracy'   ]
)
```

This is the shape for 1 sequence

**x_shape = (1, 24, 252)**

**y_shape = (1, 24, 2)**

I trained the model for at least 1 day with GPU enabled, but the accuracy and loss doesn't change very much.

It always stays between 0.3 to 0.5. ex:

```
Epoch 100/200
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/sample - loss: 0.3928 - accuracy: 0.4679
....
Epoch 194/200
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/sample - loss: 0.4061 - accuracy: 0.4893
```

The dataframe is already normalized

How I can improve the learning accuracy and loss?

Please le me know how to improve the question if is necesary

Comment: only for curiosity... what are you trying to predict?

Comment: @Marco Cerliani 
https://pythonprogramming.net/cryptocurrency-recurrent-neural-network-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/
I'm following this Sendex tutorial, but i'm got more data than him each column in the X values are % stock prices increased since the last hour and y values are the probability of buy and sell for that hour

Comment: ok, you are trying to predict the prob to buy of the next 24 hours in one-shot, correct?

Comment: yes, by the way.. thanks for the previous help

Comment: I think it's a very difficult task, especially if u are using stock data. what I suggest u is to try to reduce the forecasting time horizon. start with targets of one day ahead (1, 1, 2) and then try to increase (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 2) to check the performances

Comment: Thank you Marco, at least the model is fine